# enum class varidic parameter pack to expand with binary operator

Tags: c++, enums, variadic-templates, c++20

There is a class template working as enum class flags container:

```
template<typename E> requires is_enum<E>::value
class flags {
public:
    flags( E value ) noexcept : m_value( to_underlying( value ) ) {}

    flags operator|( const E value ) noexcept {
        m_value |= to_underlying( value );
    }

    flags & operator|=( const E value ) noexcept {
        m_value |= to_underlying( value );
        return *this;
    }

    flags & operator=( const E value ) noexcept {
        m_value = to_underlying( value );
    }

    template<E FLAG>
    bool is_set( void ) noexcept {
        return ( m_value & to_underlying( FLAG ) );
    }

private:
    /* Abstracted type to store 'combined' value */
    typename underlying_type<E>::type m_value;
};

template<typename E> requires is_enum<E>::value
flags<E> operator|( E lhs, E rhs ) noexcept {
    return ( flags( lhs ) | rhs );
}
```

and some sample flags:

```
enum class mode { MODE_0 = 1, MODE_1 = 2, MODE_2 = 4 };
```

and finally to use it like:

```
template<mode... MODES>
struct user {
   void apply( flags<mode> m = MODES | ... ) {} // <- this does not work
};

user<mode::MODE_0, mode::MODE_2> sample;
```

uses `void apply( flags<mode> m )` where `m` contains the internal `m_value` equal to `mode::MODE0 | mode::MODE2` ( m_value == 5 )

So the question is:

The goal is to take the variadic parameter pack containing the particular `modes`, combine them with `operator|` to create single `flags<mode>` instance...

so how to fix this line to make it work?

```
void apply( flags<mode> m = MODES | ... ) {} // <- this does not work
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for the [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) is incorrect; the fold expression needs to be in parentheses:

```
void apply( flags<mode> m = ( MODES | ... ) ) {}
                         // ^_____________^
```